# ASP.NET MVC: How do I change where Ajax.BeginForm will post to after the page loads?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to make an Ajax.BeginForm that will by default, go to the add user page. I also want in the same form an edit and delete button. The information in the form will be the same, I just need it to post to the different edit user and delete user URL.

How can I modify where the form will post, depending on what submit button is pressed, while keeping all the items that Ajax.BeginForm gives us.

Edit:

Also wanted to note that I want the URL to be generated by my routes. So in the same way the BeingForm uses the "action" and "controler" to make the path, I want to use that as well when I change the URL, so the URL is dynamic and not static.

Comment: Using J-Query or JavaScript you can change action url of the form

Comment: A form only posts back to one method. But why would you need to post back all values for an 'Delete' method - you should just post the ID value (and in a separate form)

Comment: @StephenMuecke The form accepts a range of ids inputted by a textbox and a checkbox. The textbox being the ids, is what I need for add, edit, and delete. The checkbox can be ignored in some of those states.I feel instead of having three textboxes in three forms that handle most of the same thing, if I can handle it all in one it would be much "cleaner".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using jquery to change the action to the form using Url.Actions.

The HTML button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="formDeleteButton" onclick="ChangeFormToDelete()">Delete</button>
```

The javascript/jQuery

```
function ChangeFormToDelete() {
            $('#UserForm').attr('action', '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "UserManagement")')
        }
```

In @Url.Action the firstparameter is the action and the second is the controller. I made the exact same functions for edit and add and it worked perfectly.

Comment: nice question, but the answer is totally unsafe.

Comment: @Aristos How is this unsafe? Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I have but unfortunately Is on forms, not on MVC and I do not have experience on MVC to answer. Now why is unsafe, I better not argue if you don't understand it... and at the end if works on you, keep it.